# Crop image footer and get original position

Tags: python, position, python-tesseract

I need to crop an image in order to get only footer informations. With this informations I get the position of the text found (with pytesseract) but with the footer-only image. So when I work with the full image, I need to have the position updated. For now here is what I have :

Crop image :

```
from wand.image import Image as Img
from wand.color import Color

with Img(filename=img, resolution=300) as pic:
    pic.compression_quality = 100
    pic.background_color = Color("white")
    pic.alpha_channel = 'remove'
    heightRatio = int(pic.height / 3 + pic.height * 0.1)
    pic.crop(0, int(pic.height - heightRatio), pic.width, pic.height)
    pic.save(filename=jpgName)
```

After that, I my text with the position like `{0: {x1,y1}, 1: {x2,y2}}` and I have the following code to try to get the position like I didn't crop the image :

```
position[0][0] = line.position[0][0]
position[1][0] = line.position[1][0]
position[0][1] = line.position[0][1] + heightRatio 
position[1][1] = line.position[1][1] + heightRatio
```

But when I show the position on the full image, it doesn't fit at all..

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer : The crop function was the issue. Using this parameters are better :

```
pic.crop(width=pic.width, height=int(pic.height - self.heightRatio), gravity='south')
```